# Ctrl + F12 not working on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys, java

I like to use swing inspector(http://www.swinginspector.com/index.html), but it uses the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> shortcut which is dependent on Glib xxx.so file which is loaded with Jar file of JAVA.
the argument is like this

```
java -agentpath:/home/manlge/swing-inspector/amd64/libswing-inspector-agent.so -classpath SwingSet2.jar SwingSet2
java -agentpath:/home/manlge/swing-inspector_1.2.3/amd64/libswing-inspector-agent.so -classpath xxx.jar xxx.xxx.Main
```

But after running a demo or jar, when I am clicking the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> the swing inspector jframe which need to come is not coming up, however when I am doing the same on Redhat 7.1 it is working.

However the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> are working fine.

Any help??